# Does "tetrahedrization" make sense?

Tags: english, latin, greek, morphemes, derivation

I am deciding on a spelling of "tessellation composed of tetrahedra" to use in my thesis.

There are four choices I know of

1. **Tetrahedralization** with 3,530 results on Google Scholar and 25,800 on Google.
2. **Tetrahedrization** with 1,130 and 10,300.
3. **Tetrahedronization** with 155 and 4,520.
4. **Tetrahedration** 118 and 420.

The way I understand it, the parts of the words are

- **tetra**, meaning four,
- **-hedron**, referring to faces, and it's corresponding adjective form **hedral**
- **-ize**, verb-forming suffix, and
- **-ation**, a suffix forming a noun out of an action.

I think I like **tetrahedrization** the most, as it's shorter and still reasonably widely used.

My question therefore is whether **tetrahedrization** is correct with respect to how we modify words coming from greek/latin, especially relative to the correctness of all the other choices.

I have a secondary question - the fact that **tetrahedration** is so uncommon surprised me, as I would otherwise prefer it due to its short length. Is there anything about it that's less suitable than the other candidates? Perhaps the fact that **-ation** would require something like **tetahedr-** to be an action, which would explain the rare occurence of **tetrahedronization**, too?

Comment: I'm new to this site and not a linguist, so any comments on how to improve the question would definitely be helpful.

Comment: I'd go for the third one. In that case only, the operative word _tetrahedron_ appears uncut and clearly meaningful. It's longer but that's generally better because it's less ambiguous, and in science you do not want ambiguity. If there is an established convention in the field, by all means go with it; but if not, then people unfamiliar with the word will read the title. You want them to understand what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the merits of the other options, I'd advise against anything beginning "tetrahedron-", because the "-on" is merely the Greek word's morphological suffix. Compare the following, where English borrows the Greek word complete with final "-on", but, when English adds suffixes, it drops that "-on".

- phenomen**on** but phenomenal
- skelet**on** but skeletal
- panthe**on** but pantheistic, pantheism

IMO the notion of "tetrahedron" is recognisable without the final "-on" -- after all, we have "tetrahedral".